# MOSS 2007 and Sharepoint desinger

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to create a custom page using sharepoint designer to save new item in the list?![alt text][1]

http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/8740/image1ed.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.

It's called creating custom list form. [See here for instructions](http://www.scribd.com/doc/9920511/Create-a-Custom-List-Form-for-a-Share-Point-List).